# Use Two Circles to Bend a Cylinder's Geometry in an Animation?

Tags: animation, modifiers, geometry

Is it possible to control the shape of a cylindrical cone using two bezier circles? (See GIF)

Currently, I am using two hook modifiers that connect all of the vertices of the cylinder to two separate empties. These empties are then parented to the bezier circles at the top and bottom of the form. Unfortunately, the cylinder position seems to drift away from the bezier circles as their position moves. I've tried to adjust the strength and fall off curves of hooks with no success.

Has anyone tried to create something similar before? What might be a better approach to achieve the desired effect?

[image: Animation of the Problem in Question]

[image: An Image of the Mesh Geometry]

Comment: This looks like a classic [Bendy Bones](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/armatures/bones/properties/bendy_bones.html) application. There's a very fine short tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MgU7qOkufU). Maybe a proper rigger can express that as an answer.

Comment: I think the issue is parenting, just use the hooks alone. Simultaneous parenting and hooks may be adding commulative transforms